# In PHP is it possible to run something after the document is returned?

Tags: php

I want to take the user's input, respond to them, and then update some stuff in the database. But the response doesn't need the stuff from the database, so I don't want the user to have to wait for it. Is there a way to say "I'm all done. Go ahead and send this to the user." but then keep executing more PHP code?

Comment: not with straight php ... and the lord said let there be ajax. and he saw what he had created and it was good.

Comment: I'm doing ajax. I'm talking about an ajax response here. I still don't want the response to wait on the database. I don't see how that's different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at exec() in php http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php.  Just before the end of processing of your php page, you can fire a command with exec() like running a php script cli: http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php (basically runs in the background.).  Be sure to note (for exec()):

If a program is started with this function, in order for it to continue running in the background, the output of the program must be redirected to a file or another output stream. Failing to do so will cause PHP to hang until the execution of the program ends.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flush, which will send the data, however it may not have the effect you're looking for (the page will still be loading).

https://www.php.net/flush

It's used when you've got an admin type script that produces iterative output but might take a while to run.